# Add font to node-canvas

Tags: node.js, fonts, path, node-canvas

I've been trying for the past hour to add font to my image unsuccessfully. Unfortunately while this may seem like a really easy thing to do I cant get it to work.

```
const Canvas = require('canvas');
var Font = Canvas.Font;
var BerlinSansFBRegular = Font ? new Font('BerlinSansFBRegular', path.join(__dirname,'./BerlinSansFBRegular.ttf')) : null;

//..

let canvas = new Canvas(GIF_WIDTH, height);
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.addFont(BerlinSansFBRegular);
context.font = `13px BerlinSansFBRegular`;
```

Directory in windows `C:\Users\...\project\fonts\BerlinSansFBRegular.ttf`, it probably has something to with the way I am giving my path cause it throws an unhandled promise rejection: Error: Not Found.

Inside the project folder is where my `.js` file and bat is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken (I don't work on Windows machines anymore), `_dirname` will return according to [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname):

> The directory name of the current module
> That is not the path you are looking for here. You want the path to the Font file, which would be from the root, `../`. I think you need to redo your path here:

```js
new Font('BerlinSansFBRegular', path.join(**__dirname**,'./BerlinSansFBRegular.ttf'))
```

To make sure I would first put the exact path in the above line:

```js
new Font('BerlinSansFBRegular', path.join(C:\Users\...\project\fonts\BerlinSansFBRegular.ttf'./BerlinSansFBRegular.ttf'))
```

and see if it returns correctly, then use the node implementation of root to file.

Remember, you always have [process_cwd](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) to find the current path.

Hope this helps.